# Turbo C MS-DOS BOX not responding to Mouse Click

Tags: turbo-c++, turbo-c

This happens to me frequently, Please give me a solution.

Edit : I have found the fix and answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Solution is just 3 Steps:**

**Step 1 :** Press **Ctrl + Alt + F**

**Step 2 :** Press **Left Arrow** (To move to the 3 Lines )

**Step 3 :** Press **Enter** on **Repaint Desktop**

You gotcha !